# Using Drools-Gorm plugin for Grails > 2.x.x without customizations

Tags: grails, grails-orm, drools, grails-plugin

I'm using Drools-Gorm plugin. A bit of code from this plugin:

**Domain**

```
class SessionInfoDomain implements SessionInfo {
  ...
  Environment env
  static transients = ['env'] 
  ...
}
```

**Service**

```
class GormDomainService {
  def SessionInfo getNewSessionInfo(Environment env) {
    return new SessionInfoDomain(env: env)
  }
}
```

But this plugin doesn't work with Grails>2.0.2 because:

**Grails 2.0.2 Data Binding Improvements** [see link](http://spring.io/blog/2012/03/28/secure-data-binding-with-grails/)
In Grails 2.0.2 the data binding mechanism will by default exclude all properties which are static, **transient** or dynamically typed, so we get *SessionInfoDomain* without *env*. We can add ( bindable:true ) in constraints of SessionInfoDomain.

My question: how to ease apply this plugin to my App without change plugin?